# What is the best way to handle post data in drupal?

Tags: forms

What function I need to implement to handle simple post data when I submit a form?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Implement a submit callback?

Comment: This question is too broad. The answer would be "you use a form submission handler," but I doubt that would be a much useful answer. Please add more details about what you are trying to achieve, and the question can possibly be re-opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement [hook_menu](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) to register a path (`api/getdata` for example) and you can post data to example.com/api/getdata path, and your `page callback` function will be able to grab `$_POST` data.

Update: 
Alright, too many downvotes and I can't delete the answer because it was accepted (can anyone do it for me ?). 
Anyways, *the question I answered* was all about handling $_POST. It just asked "how to I handle $_POST or something" and no form was mentioned. Handling some $_POST is not some kind of form everytime. (Like Paypal IPN handling). Yes you should use Form API for forms and a module like Services for REST/SOAP stuff.

Comment: dont understand why this is downvoted. Security issues are not the issue of the question.

Answer (score 6):

You are doing it Wrong(TM). Both the question(!) and especially the answer. Yes, you need to implement hook_menu but your `page_callback` is [drupal_get_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/7) because you never, ever work with `$_POST` directly for security reasons.

Comment: do I need to implement the drupal_get_form function in my module to handle $post data?

Comment: You need to read up on the Forms API.  This D6 centric, but it is a good starting point: http://drupal.org/node/751826  Otherwise, http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7